# Mocha - hooks in separate files

Tags: mocha.js

I am trying to put methods beforeEach and afterEach to a separate files because I will use them a lot.

I can not find a way to do this & will work. Can you help me out?

This is my working code:

```
describe('something', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    console.log('beforeEach');
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    console.log('afterEach');
  });

  it(...);
});
```

Comment: You can't put the *calls* in a separate file, that doesn't make sense, but you can move *the functions you pass as arguments* if you want to. It's not clear what you've tried and what the problem was, though.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.